# I can't upgrade from 12.04 beta2 to 12.04 final, neither install any lens

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lenses

**In both cases, after adding the repos (for lens), and updating, when I try install them or to upgrade ubuntu I get a similar message:**

> W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

**e.g. From terminal:**

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Calculating upgrade... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release i386 (20120423)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20120423)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
>   W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

**It is like if it is nothing to upgrade, but when I try to upgrade from the update manager i get the message: Failed to download repository information.
And in the details i get:**

> W:GPG error: h ttp://packages.medibuntu.org precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EBC26B60C5A2783, W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/pidgin/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>   , W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/pidgin/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>   , W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>   , W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>   , W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>   , W:Failed to fetch h ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>   , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following and see if it helps:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`

If the apt command does not work try aptitude just in case.

1. `sudo aptitude update`
2. `sudo aptitude upgrade`

I would also recommend commenting/removing the medibuntu ppa, or for that matter commenting/removing all PPA and just leave the default Ubuntu repositories that are officially supported by Ubuntu. That way you minimize the problems that might occurred when trying to read some PPAs (Specially the time it takes to complete updating the repositories).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know exactly how it worked but I removed the medibuntu ppa and all the ppa's that caused the problem with the update manager (lens ppa, pidgin ppa, HUD ppa, etc.)and the lens just began to work. Should I activate the ppa's again for further updates?

Comment: By the way, the update manager don't send that error again and it seems to be upgraded now.

Comment: I am glad it worked. I have also noticed that on 12.04 many problems can now be corrected very quickly. Can't wait to see 12.04 in a month or 2.